# Second directional derivative of a scaler in polar coordinate

Tags: derivatives, polar-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

I am completely confused by a second order directional derivative in pola coordinate. I need to find below derivative:

$\partial_i \partial_j f(\rho) = ?$

$i$ and $j$ are component of polar coordinate (say $\rho$ and $\phi$).

I can find gradient of $f(\rho)$ which is a tensor as below:

$\nabla f(\rho) = \partial_{\rho} f(\rho) \hat{\rho}$

What is solution to the second order partial derivative? I know that it is a tensor but I don't know how to calculate it. Any answer is highly appreciated.(Also introducing a reference for thing like laplacian of a second rank tensor is really appreciated)

Comment: Is it a really complicated question? Is there anyone who could answer it?!

Comment: Since $f$ is a function of $\rho$ only, $$\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 \phi} = \frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial \phi\partial \rho} = \frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial \rho\partial\phi} = 0$$, while $$\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 \rho} =\frac {\partial}{\partial \rho}\left(\frac {\partial f}{\partial \rho}\right)$$There is really not much more that can be said about an arbitrary function $f$.